# Doctrine OneToOne not updating relation

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

My update fails updating the records in the database of my relationship entity. I have two entities named user and user_meta as one user can just have one user_meta record I use OneToOne, if I understand the concept this should be right.

Updated data for User is updated but for UserMeta nothing happens.

**User entity**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="email", columns={"email"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 */
class User {
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", nullable=false, length=125)
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", nullable=false, length=125)
     */
    protected $password;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", nullable=false, length=25)
     */
    protected $role;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", nullable=false, length=10)
     */
    protected $status;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;
    /**
     *
     * @var $userMeta
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserMeta", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $userMeta;
    /**
     *
     * Get id
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Set email
     * @param $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Get email
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Set password
     * @param $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Get password
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Set role
     * @param $role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Get role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Set status
     * @param $status
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Get status
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
    /**
     * Set created
     * @param $created
     */
    public function setCreated(\DateTime $dateTime)
    {
        $this->created = $dateTime;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Get created
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserMeta()
    {
        return $this->userMeta;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userMeta
     */
    public function setUserMeta(UserMeta $userMeta)
    {
        $this->userMeta = $userMeta;
    }
}
```

**UserMeta entity**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users_meta")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 */
class UserMeta {
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", nullable=true, length=125)
     */
    protected $firstName;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", nullable=true, length=125)
     */
    protected $lastName;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", nullable=true, length=5)
     */
    protected $gender;
    /**
     * @var User $user
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $firstName
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $lastName
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGender()
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $gender
     */
    public function setGender($gender)
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Get user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Set user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

**Dump before calling flush**

```
object(Application\Entity\User)[368]
  protected 'id' => int 50
  protected 'email' => string 'name@domain.com' (length=22)
  protected 'password' => string 'BCRYPT_HASH' (length=60)
  protected 'role' => string 'admin' (length=5)
  protected 'status' => string 'active' (length=6)
  protected 'created' => 
    object(DateTime)[359]
      public 'date' => string '2017-01-08 10:59:55.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Amsterdam' (length=16)
  protected 'userMeta' => 
    object(Application\Entity\UserMeta)[373]
      protected 'id' => int 2
      protected 'firstName' => string 'Ivanovic' (length=5)
      protected 'lastName' => string 'Tzazinsky' (length=7)
      protected 'gender' => string 'male' (length=4)
      protected 'user' => 
        &object(Application\Entity\User)[368]
```

**Controller**

```
        $em         = $this->_getObjectManager();
        $request    = $this->getRequest();
        $form       = new UserSettingsForm($em);
        $user       = $em->find('Application\Entity\User', (int) $authService->getIdentity()->getId());
        $userEmail  = $user->getEmail();
        $userPass   = $user->getPassword();
        $userAvatar = $user->getUserMeta()->getAvatar();
        $form       ->bind($user);
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form ->setData($data);
            if ($form->isValid()) {

                // Is updated in database
                $user ->setEmail('test@testchange.com');
                $user ->setRole('admin');

                // Is NOT updated in database  
                $user->getUserMeta()->setFirstName('Ivanovic');
                $user->getUserMeta()->setLastName('Tzazinsky');

                var_dump($user);

                try {
                    $em   ->flush();
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    var_dump($e->getMessage());
                }

            } else {
                Debug::dump($form->getMessages());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are right, persist should not be necessary for updating already managed entities.

Comment: @Wilt indeed :)

Comment: The problem in my code was $unitOfWork->computeChangeSets(); This detach the child entity somehow? Turned off this function and now it works as it should :)